# How can i pass a message to a page while submitting a form?

Tags: django, django-2.0

When i submits the form i want to pass message as "form successfully submitted"  to the same page "successs.html".How it possible?

```
class SuccessView(FormView):
    template_name = 'success.html'
    form_class = QuestForm
    success_url='success'   
    def form_valid(self, form):
        ob9=Logs.objects.all()
        for i in ob9:
            logids=i.id
        str(logids)
        q1= form.cleaned_data['ques']
        obj1=Quest.objects.create(logid=logids,status=0,question=q1)
        return super(SuccessView,self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Very little of this code makes any sense. What's the point of iterating over all Logs object and setting the same variable each time? What do you think calling `str()` without assigning it to anything will do?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Django's [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/messages/), it's as simple as adding a message at any point during the call processing (this adds the message to the current `request` object) and it will be added to the response:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success("Form successfully submitted")
```

You can do this just before your call to `return super().form_valid(form)`.

In your template you need to add the code to diplay the messages of course, the example in the documentation shows you exactly how to do that.

Comment: in template how can i retrieve the message ?

Answer (score 0):

The [django message Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) offers different ways to do it:

```
 from django.contrib import messages
 messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Your message', extra_tags='more_tags')
 # extra_tags is optional
```

or

```
messages.success(request,"Your message")
```

To retrieve it in your template, use something like

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: it shows error :      success() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

Comment: you miss `request` as first argument: `messages.success(request,"Your message")`. check my answer @Anjitha , I updated it